# Understanding how $x^2+2x+y^2-6y-15=0$ becomes $(x+1)^2+(y-3)^2=25$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

I am looking at how this equation was simplified, $15$ was pushed to the other side and $10$ I believe was added by adding $1$ to the first bracket equation and $9$ to the other part.

The next part where to get $x² + 2x + 1$ to $(x + 1)^2$ there $2x$ seems to be dropped off and the same for $6y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right about the first part. The second part just uses the formula $(x+a)^2=x^2+2ax+a^2$ twice.

Comment: Thanks it's been a while since I did some math and that expansion is true. It totally makes sense now.

Comment: @SamuelM. I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 3):

***HINT***

$(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$

*completing the square*

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you’re right. The equation was simplified by completing the square. Remember that $(m+n)^2 = m^2+2mn+n^2$ and vice versa.
$$x^2+\frac{b}{a}x = -c \implies x^2+\biggr(\frac{b}{2a}\biggr)^2+\frac{b}{a}x = -c+\biggr(\frac{b}{2a}\biggr)^2$$

$$\implies \biggr(x+\frac{b}{2a}\biggr)^2 = -c+\biggr(\frac{b}{2a}\biggr)^2 \implies \biggr(x+\frac{b}{2a}\biggr)^2-\biggr(\frac{b}{2a}\biggr)^2= -c$$

This process was done for both $x$ and $y$.
$$x^2+2x+y^2-6y-15 = 0$$
Break it down into two parts. Complete the square for both $x$ and $y$.
$$(x^2+2x)+(y^2-6y)-15 = 0$$
$$(x^2 + 1^2+2x)-1^2+(y^2+3^2-6y)-3^2-15 = 0$$
$$(x+1)^2-1+(y-3)^2-9-15 = 0 \implies (x+1)^2+(y-3)^2-25 = 0$$ $$\implies (x+1)^2+(y-3)^2 = 25$$

Answer (score 0):

hint:$$x^{2}+2x=(x+1)^{2}-1$$ 
$$y^{2}-6y=(y-3)^{2}-9$$